# Getting final value of nested promises

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

When using nested promises, I can't quite figure out what is going wrong in the following implementation.
Still trying to learn and fully understand promises.

The code shows the nested promises in their functions. "arrangeAll" waits for the gathering of images from the storage that happens in "auxStorageDownload".

```
function getCurrentShop (userUID){
    const tudo = firestore
    .collection('na_publications')
        .doc(userUID)
            .collection('user_na_publications1')
    let array = []
    tudo.get().then(snapshot => {
        snapshot.forEach(doc => {
            array.push(doc.data())
          })
    }).then(() => {
            arrangeAll(array, userUID).then(res => console.log(res))
        
        }    
    )
}

async function arrangeAll (array, userUID) {
    const promises = array.map((elem, i) => {
        const result = auxStorageDownload(userUID, elem)
        return result
    })

    await Promise.all(promises).then(promise => {
        console.log(promise)
    })

}

async function auxStorageDownload (userUID, elem) {      
    let aux = []
    const promises2 = elem.images.map(photoName => {  //Fotos de cada publicacao
        let result = storage.ref(`publications/${userUID}/${elem.nomeStorage}/${photoName}`).getDownloadURL()
        return result
    })

    await Promise.all(promises2).then(promise => {
        console.log(promise)
    })
    return promises2
}
```

As you can see in the second image, the promise gathers images regarding 3 publications that have multiple photos (browser console).

[image: browser console]

But the values received in the "arrangeAll" function are promises, and I would like to use them here to build the final structures for the publications in the website.

Comment: Give us code, not screenshots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is faulty:

```
    await Promise.all(promises).then(promise => {
        console.log(promise)
    })
```

---

You need to:

- Return the promise(s) from the function.
- If you want the functions to be logged in a `then`'d function, you need to return them from that function as well.

A direct fix to your code:

```
    return await Promise.all(promises).then(promises => {
        // promises is an array of resolved values here
        console.log(promises)
        return promises;
    })
```

Also in the above code, `await`  can be dropped, since the returned Promise will be `await`ed by the outer calling function anyway (the function calling `arrangeAll`.

---

If you'd like a cleaner solution:

- Change the ending of `arrangeAll`:

```
async function arrangeAll (array, userUID) {
    const promises = array.map((elem, i) => {
        const result = auxStorageDownload(userUID, elem)
        return result
    })

    return Promise.all(promises);
}
```

- If you want to log them before returning:

```
async function arrangeAll (array, userUID) {
    const promises = array.map((elem, i) => {
        const result = auxStorageDownload(userUID, elem)
        return result
    })

    const resolved = await Promise.all(promises);
    console.log(resolved) /// resolved is an array
    return resolved;
}
```

Comment: Thank you John for your reply, the only problem is that now I have the final arrays of promises, how do I get the PromiseResult for each one?

Comment: You can just iterate over the array. The array returned by `await Promise.all([p1, p2])` contains already resolved values. `const resolved = await Promise.all(promises); resolved.forEach(val => console.log(val))`, for instance.